# How to call variable parameter method in JSP EL?

Tags: jsp, variables, parameters, el

I have a bean with a method like below:

```
public String merge(Object... l) {
    return StringUtils.join(l);
}
```

now I want to call it in JSP EL like:

```
${bean.merge('1','2','3')}
```

but the page cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Is it because JSP EL doesn't support variable-parameters feature, or just a bug in the JSP EL implementation in Apache Tomcat 7.0.19?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create EL function though which you can pass parameter. Have a look [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) tutorial and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033575/using-varargs-in-a-tag-library-descriptor) thread.