# jsf 1.2 custom function varargs signature

Tags: java, methods, jsf-1.2, method-signature

I have a custom JSF function and I need to create a custom function that has a variable length argument list:

the signature is:

```
public static boolean myFunction(String... args) {
...
}
```

how do I write the signature of the function in the taglib file?

for example, if I have just one String argument, this works:

```
<function>
    <function-name>myFunction</function-name>
    <function-class>functions.Functions</function-class>
    <function-signature>boolean myFunction(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
</function>
```

Comment: I have found myself the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033575/using-varargs-in-a-tag-library-descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, a vararg argument like `String... args` is replaced by an array argument (`String[]` in this case).

Try:

```
<function-signature>boolean myFunction(java.lang.String[])</function-signature>
```

Comment: What errors/problems occur? Perhaps post some more code, I don't think this section is the problem...

Comment: the error is that I pass two arguments or more, and the function takes only one.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when you take this approach:
http://seamframework.org/Documentation/CreatingCustomELFunctions

The idea is to not define the functions explicitly, instead loading them dynamically from a static class into the library. Only problem for me is that Netbeans does not recognize the library this way.